# Binary Tree in Python using OOP. Problem with comparing instances

Tags: python, oop

I was trying to create a program for a binary tree, but while running the search function, I came across an error.

My program

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,item):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.item = item
    def insert(self, item):
        if self.item:
            if item < self.item:
                if self.left is None:
                    self.left = Node(item)
                else:
                    self.left.insert(item)
            elif item > self.item:
                if self.right is None:
                   self.right = Node(item)
                else:
                    self.right.insert(item)
        else:
            self.item = item
    def search(self, item):
        while self.item != item:
            copy1 = item
            copy2 = self.item
            if copy1 < copy2:
                self.item = self.left
            else:
                self.item = self.right
            if self.item is None:
                return False
        return self.item
```

The code for input (insert and search):

```
tree = Node(27)

tree.insert(19)
tree.insert(36)
tree.insert(42)
tree.insert(16)

print("Do you wish to search for a number in the tree?")
flag = 1
while True:
    num = int(input("Please enter the number you wish to search for \n"))
    x = tree.search(num)
    if x == False:
        print("The number is not present")
    else:
        print("The number is present", x)
    flag = int(input("If you wish to continue searching, enter 1, else enter 0 \n"))
```

searching for 27 gave a positive result, but when I searched for 19, the following error was shown

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Py School\Binary Trees\Binary Tree (Classes).py", line 43, in <module>
    x = tree.search(num)
  File "e:\Py School\Binary Trees\Binary Tree (Classes).py", line 24, in search  
    if copy1 < copy2:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Node'
```

Is there any way to compare between the instances that would work, or is there something wrong with my code?

I tried loading the values of "item" and "self.item" into separate variables and the compare the variables, but the error was still the same. I tried using int(self.item) for comparison but that did not work as well

Comment: Stepping back from your immediate problem, the `search` method should just search: it should not modify the tree, right? So changing `self.item` in that method will be a problem. Likely you want to initialise something like `search_pointer = self`, then iteratively change `search_pointer` according to the results of your comparison.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by `slothrop`, you shouldn't do `self.item = ...` since the search will then be modifying the tree itself.

With the specific error, you seem to be changing the type from `int` to `Node`: `self.item` = `self.left` where `self.left` is a `Node`.

Here is a modified function:

```
def search(self, item):
    currentNode = self # can also just reassign self but could be confusing
    while currentNode.item != item:
        if item < currentNode.item: # always 2 int
            currentNode = currentNode.left # doesn't modify self to reassign currentNode
        else:
            currentNode = currentNode.right # currentNode and currentNode.right are both type Node (or NoneType)
        if currentNode is None:
            return False
    return currentNode.item
```